# ALSA configuration to enable device sharing between multiple processes

Tags: c, linux, pcm, alsa

I have the following code in the `.asoundrc` file in my home directory -

```
pcm.lol
{
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave{
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        period_time 125000
        rate 48000
        format S32_LE
        channels 2
    }
}
```

When I run [this sample example](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html) it works fine (I changed the device name to `plug:lol`). I can hear a sound playing in my headphones. The problem occurs when two or more processes try to output audio data at the same time. In this case, the later process cannot output its audio data properly.

For example, I ran a media player which was playing a song and then I tried running that example. I couldn't hear any sound from it, all I could hear was the music playing in the media player. Similar thing happens when I run this example first and then the media player, in which case I only listen audio output from my example.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any error with my pcm device configuration? Or do I have to provide any additional PCM configuration parameters in the example code ?

Also, it would have been really nice if I could create this logical device configuration programmatically rather than using a configuration file like this.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: @Till: Well I wanted to know if there is a "programming related" way to configure all these, i.e., using ALSA PCM API. So I thought may be this is programming related.....

Comment: fair enough - makes sense and pushes this question right in-between Superuser and SO :D - hope you find a sufficient answer.

Comment: @Till: Thank you, but I asked a similar question before, couldn't find any appropriate solution...looks like this one is going to be closed though...

Comment: Right, I was one of those and feel that I prematurely voted to move this to Superuser. My bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have searched and checked, there is apparently no concrete way to do this in ALSA. I can share the built-in `default` device between multiple processes, but any other configuration didn't provide this functionality. Also, I couldn't find any programmatic way to configure an ALSA device. The configuration file seems to be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your sound output is still defaulting to hw0,0, but you want it to default to lol, so you'll need to follow the example from the [ALSA website](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Software_mixing) and add the following to the beginning of your .asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "lol"
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any programmatic way of configuring .asoundrc.